Recaptcha v2 Callback - Struggling with 2Captcha Solve
I am trying to solve a recaptcha v2 with callback, the recaptcha is the picture solving. I'm not entirely sure what my issue is because I only get hit with the recaptcha when I am in headless mode.
I am successfully extracting the Callback and sending with the solve. When this happens, the webpage advances to the next page. But the captcha window is still open. I am struggling to click the "verify" button -I am trying various methods to switch to the iframe but the "verify" button is not found- whether I use xpath, CSS etc
Can anyone help figure out where I am going wrong with this?
def solve_recaptcha(api_key, site_key, url):
    print(f"Sending sitekey to 2Captcha: {site_key}")
    # Send the sitekey to 2Captcha for solving
    response = requests.post(
        'http://2captcha.com/in.php',
        data={
            'key': api_key,
            'method': 'userrecaptcha',
            'googlekey': site_key,
            'pageurl': url
        }
    )
    print(f"2Captcha response: {response.text}")
    if response.text.startswith('OK|'):
        captcha_id = response.text.split('|')[1]
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Error from 2Captcha: {response.text}")

    # Retrieve the CAPTCHA solution
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        result = requests.get(f'http://2captcha.com/res.php?key={api_key}&action=get&id={captcha_id}')
        if result.text == 'CAPCHA_NOT_READY':
            continue
        if result.text.startswith('OK|'):
            captcha_solution = result.text.split('|')[1]
            break
        else:
            raise Exception(f"Error from 2Captcha: {result.text}")

    print(f"CAPTCHA Solution: {captcha_solution}")
    return captcha_solution

try:


    # JavaScript function to find reCAPTCHA clients
    find_recaptcha_clients_js = """
    function findRecaptchaClients() {
      if (typeof (___grecaptcha_cfg) !== 'undefined') {
        return Object.entries(___grecaptcha_cfg.clients).map(([cid, client]) => {
          const data = { id: cid, version: cid >= 10000 ? 'V3' : 'V2' };
          const objects = Object.entries(client).filter(([_, value]) => value && typeof value === 'object');

          objects.forEach(([toplevelKey, toplevel]) => {
            const found = Object.entries(toplevel).find(([_, value]) => (
              value && typeof value === 'object' && 'sitekey' in value && 'size' in value
            ));

            if (typeof toplevel === 'object' && toplevel instanceof HTMLElement && toplevel['tagName'] === 'DIV'){
                data.pageurl = toplevel.baseURI;
            }

            if (found) {
              const [sublevelKey, sublevel] = found;

              data.sitekey = sublevel.sitekey;
              const callbackKey = data.version === 'V2' ? 'callback' : 'promise-callback';
              const callback = sublevel[callbackKey];
              if (!callback) {
                data.callback = null;
                data.function = null;
              } else {
                data.function = callback;
                const keys = [cid, toplevelKey, sublevelKey, callbackKey].map((key) => `['${key}']`).join('');
                data.callback = `___grecaptcha_cfg.clients${keys}`;
              }
            }
          });
          return data;
        });
      }
      return [];
    }
    return findRecaptchaClients();
    """

    # Execute the JavaScript function to get reCAPTCHA clients data
    recaptcha_data = driver.execute_script(find_recaptcha_clients_js)
    print(f"reCAPTCHA Data: {recaptcha_data}")

    if recaptcha_data:
        # Assuming the first reCAPTCHA client found is the target
        recaptcha_info = recaptcha_data[0]
        site_key = recaptcha_info['sitekey']
        callback_function = recaptcha_info.get('callback')

        # Solve the reCAPTCHA
        captcha_solution = solve_recaptcha(api_key, site_key, url)

        # Inject the solved token into the page
        driver.execute_script(f"document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').innerHTML='{captcha_solution}';")

        # Execute the callback function if it exists
        if callback_function:
            driver.execute_script(f"var callback = {callback_function}; callback('{captcha_solution}');")
        

        print("CAPTCHA solved and token submitted successfully.")
    else:
        print("No reCAPTCHA found on the page.")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")


I attaches some pics to show how the page is advancing after submitting solve

As you can see, the page advances after submitting the solve, but iframe containing captcha is still present
Switching to iframe with
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id*='verify']")))

    # Click the button
    button.click()
    print("Button clicked successfully!")


some servers may detect selenium and maybe this can be the problem

Could switching to puppeteer/node be better?

first you could test selenium with driver undetected-chromedriver

i tried using undetected chromedriver but still get flagged for recaptcha when im in headless mode :-/
